# VHDL error related to Choises

Tags: vhdl

I am making a N to 2^N decoder and facing some errors. Please help me out.

- `Naddr` - Number of address bits integer
- `addr` - address bits `std_logic_vector`
- `fbd` - (integer, `std_logic_vector`) - Function for conversion from
  binary to decimal
- `fpower` - (integer) - Function to provide 2^N

Code:

```
Architecture deco of Deco is   
begin  

process(addr, En)  
  variable a : integer;  
begin  
  a := fbd(Naddr, addr);  
  if(En = '1') then  
    q <= (a => '1', others => '0'); --- error1           
  elsif(En = '0') then  
    q <= (fpower(Naddr)-1 downto 0 => '0');  
  end if;  
end process;  

end deco;
```

The error I get are:

> 1) Error (10318): VHDL aggregate error at Deco.vhd(33): choice must be
>   constant (error1)
>
> 2) Error: Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct VHDL (assuming Naddr is constant) and will work in simulation. (It is not *good* VHDL but that's another matter)

However it cannot be translated into working hardware by current synthesis tools : consider that you want to wire one bit to '1' but you don't know which bit that is until the circuit is complete and powered up ... what would such a piece of hardware look like? Draw it out on paper using simple logic elements.

Give up?

Now design a simple circuit that can set ANY bit to '1' depending on an "if" condition for each bit...

```
process(addr, En)
variable a : integer;
begin
    a := fbd(Naddr, addr);  
    if En = '1' then  
       q <= (others => '0');
       for i in q'range loop
          if i = a then
             q(i) <= '1';
          end if;
       end loop;
    end if;
end process;
```

As this all takes place within a single process, there is only one driver for Q here, despite the fact that there is more than one assignment to Q.

You will also have to learn the benefits of **clocked processes**, but not in this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.......:)
But instead of making a loop why cant i write simply q(a) <= '1' in if statement as when this statement will execute i will have the value of 'a' in my hand????????

Comment: Because you DON'T have the value of 'a' in hand when you are generating the logic that goes into the FPGA! Unless 'a' is a CONSTANT in which case, declare it a constant instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
q <= (a => '1', others => '0'); --- error1
```

Suppose q is a bit vector, and the value of 'a' at the time this statement is being executed is 4. Then you're saying make all bits 0 except bit 4. Make 'q[4] =1'.
However, VHDL does not allow the position of the bit to be specified as a variable. Its value has to be known at the time of compilation. So this can be a constant, or a generic parameter, but not a signal or variable.

You seem to be approaching VHDL like C programming... Its a bad idea to use logs, integers etc for making a simple decoder. See [this](http://computer-programming-forum.com/42-vhdl/91040f71c27e047d.htm) link for a simple 8 to 256 bit decoder

Comment: Yup thanks for your solution.........and i have done the same as given by your link at some extent........but thanks for making my VHDL concepts more clear........thank you very much.......